# Base and "Derived" Grid View - XAML issue

Tags: silverlight, xaml, user-controls

Is it possible to create base user control with GridView without column definition
and then to provide later that columns definition in XAML of other user control
that has that base user control embedded inside (so base user control with GridView
is child control of other user control)? I try to do it in Silverlight.

I created DependencyProperty on base user control level that exposes Telerik GridView,
but in user control that has this user control as a child control I can't override GridView object or change column definition. I mean I provided such Grid/Column definition on parent/outer user control and XAML compilation works ok, but I see test column defined on base user control all the time...

Comment: If you are only overriding GridView behaviour, and not adding xaml, you might as well create a custom control instead of a UserControl by inheriting directly from GridView. You will need to change the xaml to use GridView instead of UserControl as the top level xaml item.

Comment: I did it already also of course :) I don't use "raw" version of Telerik Rad GridView on my user controls but derived version that works fine. Unfortunately I need user control because I put there many different controls that form my "complex" user control that I want to use in my code as some kind of black box. And when I use this black box in some user control I'd like to provide proper columns definition for a grid there